# Ubuntu dual boot: Gparted cannot increase partition size

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have installed Windows and Ubuntu on the same NVME but on different partitions; (I have now clue! why there are 3 Win-recovery partitions) Probably windows, thats why...

```
Device      Start        End          Sectors      Size   Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    923647    921600   450M Windows-Recovery
/dev/nvme0n1p2    923648   1126399    202752    99M EFI-System
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1126400   1159167     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4   1159168 817598519 816439352 389,3G Microsoft Basis
/dev/nvme0n1p5 817600512 818739199   1138688   556M Windows-Recovery
/dev/nvme0n1p6 818741248 974942207 156200960  74,5G Linux-Filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7 974942208 974991359     49152    24M BIOS boot
/dev/nvme0n1p8 974993408 976771071   1777664   868M Windows-Recovery
```

`nvme0n1p4` is windows, `nvme0n1p6`is Ubuntu.

**Partitions in Gparted;** I want to give the nvme0n1p6 the unlocated extra space.
[image: gparted]
**But Gparted does not allow me to;**
[image: size restriction]

**How can I increase the size of my Ubuntu partition?**

Comment: Only use Windows on NTFS partition resize or change. And only use gparted on Linux partitions. That helps to avoid issues. Windows typically requires chkdsk after a resize or change. You should be UEFI booting, and then would not need p7, the bios_grub partition. That is only for BIOS boot of Ubuntu on gpt partitioned drives. But make sure you are UEFI booting. Not sure how you would have a bios_grub on an UEFI system anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I guess it appeared when I ran `sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p6` to fix my ubuntu when it was not booting. Maybe it also was `e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sda`. Weird thing is, I cannot select my ubuntu for UEFI boot. I have to select the main drive "NVME PCIe SSD" in legacy boot mode to start ubuntu.

Comment: Then you installed Ubuntu in the old BIOS boot mode. And that is why you have a bios_grub partition. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible, once you start booting in one mode or the other, you cannot change modes. Or grub only boots other installs in same boot mode. Best if all installs in same boot mode, which often is defined as how you have Windows installed UEFI or BIOS. And if newer UEFI hardware best if all installs are UEFI.

Answer (score 2):

To increase the size of a partition, you need to have the partition and an unallocated space that are neighbors, I don't know Windows partion scheme too much so I can't tell you if you can safely delete `nvme0n1p5`

Answer (score 2):

[Nicolas](https://askubuntu.com/a/1322822/20358) is correct that you need to move the free space next to the partition you want to expand. You could move partition 0n1p5 in front of the free space, rather than deleting it; but there's no guarantee that will work okay either. Give yourself room to experiment by taking a [low-level back-up](https://www.marksanborn.net/howto/make-a-backup-image-of-your-hard-drive-with-dd/)<sup>1</sup> of your entire drive. Make sure you understand how to restore before you get started.

Experimenting with partitions is tricky business, and there's always a possibility to lose data, even if you have experience with tricky business — there's always the chance that you'll forget a step, and be half-way done, with no way to undo your work. A reliable backup is key to success.

With my or Nicolas' suggestion, there's a chance you'll corrupt your Windows boot process, which is easy to notice and restore from backup. However, you could also add subtle problems that make it much harder to recover Windows in the unlikely event that it crashes later on. OTOH, you can probably delete all the Windows recovery partitions without any immediate effects, as long as you have a way to re-install Windows. (Disclaimer: Haven't tried; take a backup.)

1 <sub>A file-level backup is not enough, because you're playing at a level below the filesystem. For this experiment, you want to backup the whole hard drive, and not just individual partitions. I recommend a byte-for-byte copy with something like `dd` unless you have a whole-hard-drive recovery program you already trust. `dd` is the slowest option, because it faithfully copies all of the blank space on your drive as well; but it has far fewer ways it can go wrong because it doesn't try to interpret the data at all. The biggest issue with `dd` is trying to understand the command line, so don't run it until you understand exactly where the data's going to be written to.</sub>

---